# How do I find the value of textarea in jQuery cloned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the value of a textarea that exists inside a cloned element, and then change that value, but I keep getting 'undefined' values when I write them out to the console.

my template:

```
<script type="text/template" data-template="test">
    <div id="content">
        <textarea id="txta">123</textarea>
    </div>
</script>
```

my js code:

```
$("#btnChange").on('click', function() {
    var templateName = 'test';
    var html;
    var el;
    el = $("script[data-template=" + templateName + "]");
    html = el.html();
    console.log('html: ' + html);                     //**this works**

    var clone = $(el).clone();
    console.log("clone: " + clone.html());            //**this works**

    var textarea = $(clone).find("textarea");
    console.log("txt val: " + textarea.val());        //**undefined**

    textarea.val("abc");
    console.log("txt val: " + textarea.val());
});
```

Comment: What you are trying with clone?

Comment: +1 Apologies. I cleaned up the title and code removed my close vote, up voted, and favorited. I have never seen `<script type="text/template"` nor `.parseHTML`. I have been doing this with hidden divs and had no idea this existed as common practice. I .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clone` is the script tag which contains text. Therefore, it doesn't contain a textarea for you to manipulate. you have to convert the text into a dom fragment.

```
var textarea = $(clone.html()).find("textarea");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/wtUBQ/

Note, that doesn't actually change `clone` in any way.

I'd suggest doing it this way:

```
$("#btnChange").on('click', function () {
    var templateName = 'test';
    var html;
    var el;
    el = $("script[data-template=" + templateName + "]");
    html = el.html();
    console.log('html: ' + html); //**this works**

    var template = $.parseHTML($(el).text());
    console.log("template: " + template); //**this works**
    var textarea = $(template).find("textarea");
    console.log("txt val: " + textarea.val()); //**undefined**

    textarea.val("abc");
    console.log("txt val: " + textarea.val());
    $("body").append(template);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/wtUBQ/1/

Comment: I'm not sure how common it is, generally when you do this you have a templating engine doing all the work rather than what i did above.